# Two different domain for specific languages pointing to one site

Tags: redirect, multilingual

I am developing a blog for a client and he needs it to be bilingual (English and Spanish). Now what he wants is that the users can get to the content with correct language based on the domain; e.g. John enters `www.domain.com` and he gets the English version and Juan enters `www.elsenordominio.com` to get the Spanish version.

All content will be validated by PHP so the users and search engines only reads the domain related language.

What do I need to use header re-direct or `301`? Is it bad for SEO? Will google penalize me?